# for loop undefined 'error'

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console.log

What I'm trying to do is make the empty array log the years-array in a for loop. The years are showing up perfectly fine, but I keep getting `undefined` at the end of the console. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

P.S - Self-taught developer here so please bear with me, thank you!

```
var empty = [];

var years = [1996, 1997, 2001, 1975, 1943];

for(var empty = 0; empty <= years.length; empty++) {
    console.log(years[empty]);
}
```

Comment: `<=` ... means empty will be 0...5 ... but only indexes 0...4 (that's a count of 5) are defined

Comment: Since you have `empty <= years.length` on the last loop `empty` will be `5`. There is no such index in `years`, hence why you get `undefined`.

Comment: The variable `empy` is defined twice, first as an array, then as a number. (and *empty* is not a good name. In the for-loop you could use *index*, *idx* or just *i*). The length of your years is 5 elements, and the first element is at index 0, so only index 0 to 4 is defined, not index 5. Change `<=` to `<` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An `array` where you are starting from index to `0` and going upto `array's length` one by one. Let us suppose

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Now this `array` contains `5 elements`. Well, if you start counting it from `0`, your `fifth element index` is `4`. But in your `loop` you are breaking it when the index is 5. As there is no element on `index 5` you are getting error undefined.

**solution**
Where you check if index is `<=` replace that with `<` as when the loop index reaches equals to the total number element in your array which is 5 it get break and exit.

Answer (score 0):

On last iteration your `empty === 5`, so `5 <= years.length === true`, thus the for loop body executes with `console.log(years[5])` which is `undefined`, since array keys are 0-based, e.g. `[0: 1996, 1: 1997, 2: 2001, 3: 1975, 4: 1943]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
var empty = [];

var years = [1996, 1997, 2001, 1975, 1943];

for(var empty = 0; empty < years.length; empty++) {
    console.log(years[empty]);
}
```

You said you are learning, look up for why arrays index start with 0.

Answer (score -2):

You see `undefined` because you're enumerating past the length of the array.

--

Try this new syntax:

```
const years = [1996, 1997, 2001, 1975, 1943];

for(let year of years) {
    console.log(year);
}
```

Or a functional style, see Array.prototype.map

```
years.map(year => console.log(year))
```