# can not read property of undefined when working in loop in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an object

```
let data = [
  { 
    name="xyz",
    property: [{ value:23 }, {value:45}]
  },
  { 
    name="abc",
    property: [{ value:23 }, {value:45}]
  }
]
```

I am running a loop

```
for(let i=0; i<=data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i].property) // consoling the proprty array of first element 
  data[i].property.map(el => { //trowing the error can't read property of 
    undefined
    ...code here
  })
}
```

I don't know why is it happening I am using react functional component, I also tried saving the value in a variable first

```
for(let i=0; i<=data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i].property) // consoling the proprty array of first element 
  let temp = data[i].property; //trowing the error here can't read property of undefined
  temp.map(el => { 
    ...code here
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you please show complete code. There is nothing wrong in the code you showed.

Comment: `i < data.length` not `i <= data.length`. Duplicate: [for loop undefined 'error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283058)

Comment: FYI: It's `console.log();` not `cosnole.log();`

Comment: @adiga my bad it's silly it was for sure breaking at the last iteration, sometimes simple things take the most of the time thank you.

Comment: Whenever you're unsure, just add lots of `debugger;` and `console.log()` for you values. Open the browser's dev tools, run the application and verify each line. You can search for resources on how to debug your code if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: BTW you can delete the question as it was just a typo and the question has no future value to the site.